# Phonegap: Can't get Barcode Scanner plugin to work

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to create a barcode scanner app using Phonegap. I am testing on an iPhone 6s with the Phonegap Developer app.

When I click the scan button, nothing happens at all.

Aside from editting the index.html file and using the Phonegap Desktop app as a server, are there any other steps I need to take?

This is my first hybrid app. My target platform and version is iOS 9.

I am just using the PhoneGap desktop app and the PhoneGap development app on my phone. Do I need to undertake another step (build etc?) Is this why it's not working?

Here is my index.html page (copied from on here, given as a working example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="scanBarcode()">Scan</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script>
    function scanBarcode(){

cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  }, 
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  }
 );
}

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? What is your target platform and their target versions? Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: thanks for your answers. You have several issues, some of which are not related to barcode scanners. 1. The Desktop App is a training tool. You will notice it is in **Beta**. So some things will not work. 2. There is NO official documentation for the **Desktop App**, except the doc that encourages people to use it. 3. Sometimes a developer needs update to the latest version, but has no way to find this out. 4. iOS9 has support issues. A such, you \*might\* be able to fix your issue, if you upgrade.

Comment: 5. There is no "official list" of plugins that work with the *Desktop App* .Lastly, I recommend you read the **bold sentences** of this FAQ. [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: Let me know what you think, so we can work on a solution.